# Market basket analysis in python

Tags: python, market-basket-analysis

I am doing market basket analysis on a xlsx dataset of a shoe store 
My Data set is like

ReceiptID  |  ItemName | Category  | NetQty

123         | Black Shoe | Shoes      | 5

123         | Brown Shoe | Shoes     | 4

125         | Sandal     | Sandal    | 2

125         | Peshawari  | Shoes     | 1

I want my data to be like

ReceiptID  |       ItemName          | Category     | NetQty

123         | Black Shoe, Brown Shoe   | Shoes        |   9

125         | Sandal, Peshawari        | Sandal, Shoes|   3

```
def new_list(items): 
   Row_list=[ ] 
   for rows in items.ReceiptID: 
     if items.ReceiptD==ReceiptID-1: 
       my_list=[items.ItemName] 
       Row_list.append(my_list) 
     return(Row_list)
```

I want a function in python that does this if i load the dataframe in it. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mind to show us what you achieved so far?

Comment: def new_list(items):
       Row_list=[ ]
       for rows in items.ReceiptID:
             if items.ReceiptD==ReceiptID-1:
                  my_list=[items.ItemName]
                  Row_list.append(my_list)
                 return(Row_list)

Comment: this function doesnt work and i dont have any clue how to make it work

Comment: @HammadIqbal Please update the question with the code rather than putting it in a comment -- it is hard to read as is.

Comment: updated!!!!!!!!!

Comment: HELPPPP!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Pleaseeee

Comment: Isn't it just about a group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need just `groupby` + `agg` as followng

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"ReceiptID": [123,123,125,125],
                   "ItemName": ["Black Shoe", "Broen Shoe", "Sandal", "Peshawari"],
                   "Category": ["Shoes", "Shoes", "Sandal" ,"Shoes"],
                   "NetQty": [5,4,2,1]})


out = df.groupby("ReceiptID")\
        .agg({"ItemName":"unique",
              "Category":"unique",
              "NetQty":"sum"})\
        .reset_index()
```

```sh
   ReceiptID                  ItemName         Category  NetQty
0        123  [Black Shoe, Broen Shoe]          [Shoes]       9
1        125       [Sandal, Peshawari]  [Sandal, Shoes]       3
```

If you want just strings instead of lists you can add these two lines

```py
for col in ["ItemName", "Category"]:
    out[col] = out[col].str.join(", ")
```

```sh
   ReceiptID                ItemName       Category  NetQty
0        123  Black Shoe, Broen Shoe          Shoes       9
1        125       Sandal, Peshawari  Sandal, Shoes       3
```